# kendo grid grouping does not display groups in alphabetical order

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid

I am having an issue trying to get the grid display grouped on a particular column show up with the groups listed in alphabetical order.  I have 200+ records whereby one particular column has about 5 different unique data elements.  I want to group the grid display on this field.  When I drag the column header to the group are of the grid, the grid displays the data grouped by this field, however not in alphabetical order.  I would expect the results to be:

Group A:
    (multiple rows...)
Group B:
    (multiple rows...)
Group C:
    (multiple rows...)
Group D:
    (multiple rows...)
Group E:
    (multiple rows...)

Instead, i get a random listing of groups without the headings being sorted at all

Group C:
    (multiple rows...)
Group A:
    (multiple rows...)
Group D:
    (multiple rows...)
Group E:
    (multiple rows...)
Group B:
    (multiple rows...)

I have not found in the Progress/Telerik online documentation where I can tell the grouping to list the groups by their group headers in alphabetical order.

Any explanation of even a link to example code where this is being done is appreciated?  Thank you...

Comment: Group columns are sorted by default. If this is not happening with your grid there may be many causes (group event handling, datasource configurations, etc.). Post your grid and datasource code, and some sample data if possible.

Comment: Hi Orilux, thanks for looking at this for me.  As it turns out, the issue has to do with Guids that are being grouped on vs. the text in the field.  We need to modify how we are populating the data in the cells and then the default sort should work.  Thanks again.